# How do I add multiple inputs from a prompt in an array together?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was instructed to create a program that takes 10 numbers from a user. Then it should display it and find its difference from the average (from the 10 numbers inputted.) I've messed around with the code for a while but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I open in browser, the calculations aren't correct.

```
var number = new Array(10);
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
var number = prompt("PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER");
total =  parseInt(number);
average = total/10; 
document.write("The difference from the average for the number, " + number + 
"is equal to " + (number - average) +  "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Well `total` is not a total. Therefore `average` is not the average, and `number` is not an array after the code ran.

Answer (score 2):

At first you don't need an array at all, you just need the total summed up:

```js
var total = 0;

for (var count = 1; count <= 10; count++) {
  const number = parseInt(prompt("A number (again):"));
  //increase total by the inputted number
  total += number;
  const average = total / count;
  document.body.innerHTML += `The ${count} number is ${number}, the average is ${average} and they differ by ${average - number}`;
}
```

You may notice that I've used `const` as much as possible ( cause constant things are better to handle ), as well as a *template literal* ( the `${..}` stuff ) which makes it more readable in my opinion.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I took the liberty to convert that to a runnable snippet.

Comment: @msanford thanks ;) i couldnt cause someone hid that button on mobile devices...

Comment: I wish I could +10 for you writing that on a mobile device. Probably good that you can't use the snip editor, it would be awful on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var number = new Array(10);
    var total; //create a variable for your total
    var average; //create a variable for your average
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) 
    {
    var number[i] = prompt("PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER"); //make sure all the 
                                                     //numbers have their 
                                                     //own ids which is 'i' 
                                                     //in this case
    total +=  parseInt(number); //this basically means total = previoustotal        
             //+ newly parsed number
    }

    average = total/10; //leave this outside because you want to do the 
                        //calculations at the end

    for(var i=0; i < number.length ; i++)
    {
    document.write("The difference from the average for the number," +
    number[i] + "is equal to " + (number[i] - average) +  "<br>");
    } //this will print out a difference output for all 10 numbers you 
      //inputted
```

Not sure how your CSS and HTML was made so i'll just leave the br in there

Answer (score 0):

It's because your every input starts calculating the average even before you get the other numbers. You would want to wait for all the input and then do the computation.

And for total you have to add numbers. Probably all you need is to get your math right.

```js
var number = new Array(10);
var total = 0;
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
   number[i] = parseInt(prompt("PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER\n"));
   total +=  parseInt(number[i]);
}
var average = total / number.length
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    alert("The difference from the average for the number, " + number[i] + 
"is equal to " + (number[i] - average));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hello to my dear friend , first of i have a question do you code for console or web ?

if you doing for console you must write like this :

```
var number = new Array(10);
var total = 0;
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
var number = console.log("PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER\n");
total = total + parseInt(readline());
}
average = total/10; 
console.log("The difference from the average for the number, " + number + 
"is equal to " + (number - average));
```

and for your way you can simply just change your code to :

```
var number = new Array(10);
var total = 0 ; 
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var number = prompt("PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER");
    total = total + parseInt(number);
    }
    average = total/5; 
    document.write("The difference from the average for the number, " + number + 
    "is equal to " + (number - average) +  "<br>");
```

```js
var number = new Array(10);
var total = 0 ; 
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var number = prompt("PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER");
    total = total + parseInt(number);
    }
    average = total/5; 
    document.write("The difference from the average for the number, " + number + 
    "is equal to " + (number - average) +  "<br>");
```

Comment: OP uses `prompt()` so you know the answer :)

Comment: what OP is ? my friend???

Comment: It means Original Poster. The person who asked the question.

Comment: OP is how on this site we usually refer to who posts the question

Comment: tnx , if my answer is helpful plz rate me